# Relation Algebra: Selection of Cartesian Product

Tags: select, relational-algebra

I am learning Relational Algebra basics for sql. I came across an example where the selection of cartesian product of two relations (R1 x R2) has been taken and I realize that it is same as selection(R1) x selection(R2). I checked the cardinalities of both and it turns out to be correct. Is it always true? If so, does it mean that this operator, mathematically speaking, satisfies the equation f(x.y) = f(x).f(y) where f can be considered selection operation?